# QSignalBlocker in Qml/QtQuick2?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to set the currentIndex of a ComboBox dynamically without triggering my attached signal.

I am currently using a bool property to set a flag that gets cleared when my signal gets called.

```
Item {
    property bool ignoreNextChanged: false

    CustomCppItem  {
        id: customItem

        onSomethingHappened: {
            ignoreNextChanged = true
            comboBox.currentIndex = 42
        }
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox

        currentIndex: -1
        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            if(ignoreNextChanged) {
                ignoreNextChanged = false
                return
            }

            // Removed code here
        }
    }
}
```

Coming from Qt/C++, I would like to use some sort of [QSignalBlocker](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) here instead of my own property.

Is there some equivalent in Qml/QtQuick2?

Comment: Without knowing more details, attempting to block a property change signal *seems* kind of like a hack. Can you elaborate on what you are really trying to do? You might have a good reason for this, but there might be a better way...

Comment: The `CustomCppItem` in my case is a QQuickPaintedItem which calls a library for map drawing. When I select an item from the combobox, I want to tell the MapItem which area should be focused. There are cases where I override the combobox selection where I dont want to change the map focus. In those cases, I am setting `ignoreNextChanged` to true. If this is already the best way, I wont change it.

Comment: How would the flag get cleared with a signal blocker? Currently it gets cleared in your signal handler.

Comment: I think I could clear it right after the `currentIndex = 42`, right?

Comment: @DanielBrunner - Thanks for the explanation. Even though this is all in the same QML file, the reason I said this is odd is because the logic for the map to decide how to react to to a combo box change is being handled by the ComboBox item and not by the map/CusomCppItem itself. I would setup a Connection such that `CustomCppItem` can listen for `comboBox.onCurrentIndexChanged` itself (or another signal thrown from onCurrentIndexChanged). And then your map can decide how to react.

Answer (score 2):

For this I would implement an [attached type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#providing-attached-objects-for-data-annotations) in c++ :

**signalblockerattachedtype.h** :

```
#ifndef SIGNALBLOCKERATTACHEDTYPE_H
#define SIGNALBLOCKERATTACHEDTYPE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <qqml.h>

class SignalBlockerAttachedType : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool enabled READ enabled WRITE setEnabled NOTIFY enabledChanged)

public:
    explicit SignalBlockerAttachedType(QObject *object = nullptr) : QObject(object), m_object(object)
    {
    }

    ~SignalBlockerAttachedType() {
        if (m_object)
            m_object->blockSignals(false);
    }

    bool enabled() const
    {
        return m_enabled;
    }
    void setEnabled(bool enabled)
    {
        if (m_enabled == enabled)
            return;

        if (m_object)
            m_object->blockSignals(enabled);

        m_enabled = enabled;
        emit enabledChanged();
    }

    static SignalBlockerAttachedType *qmlAttachedProperties(QObject *object) {
        return new SignalBlockerAttachedType(object);
    }

signals:
    void enabledChanged();

private:
    bool m_enabled = false;
    QObject *m_object;
};

QML_DECLARE_TYPEINFO(SignalBlockerAttachedType, QML_HAS_ATTACHED_PROPERTIES)

#endif // SIGNALBLOCKERATTACHEDTYPE_H
```

---

**main.cpp** :

```
#include "signalblockerattachedtype.h"
// ...
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<SignalBlockerAttachedType>("fr.grecko.SignalBlocker", 1, 0, "SignalBlocker", "SignalBlocker is only available as an attached type.");
// ...
engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/usage.qml")));
```

---

**usage.qml** :

```
import fr.grecko.SignalBlocker 1.0
// ...

Item {
    id: rootItem
    property alias currentIndex: comboBox.currentIndex
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        // this won't get called from a change in onSomethingHappened
    }
    CustomCppItem  {
        id: customItem

        onSomethingHappened: {
            rootItem.SignalBlocker.enabled = true;
            rootItem.currentIndex = 42
            rootItem.SignalBlocker.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        currentIndex: -1
    }
}
```

Even though the `SignalBlocker` works on the `ComboBox`, you don't want to put it on the `ComboBox`. Doing so will prevent it to update its display when the index changes.

In your situation, I don't think this solution is better than using a simple flag.